# ThrottlerGuard not working on Websocket in Nestjs

Tags: websocket, nestjs, throttling

I'm creating an application that is using Nestjs with websockets, but now I need to add rate limit on the sockets, but analyzing the documentation [documentation link](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting#websockets) and implementing what it says in it, when I use @UseGuards(MyGuard) an error occurs in the application.

My Guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class NewThrottlerGuard extends ThrottlerGuard {
  protected async handleRequest(
    context: ExecutionContext,
    limit: number,
    ttl: number,
  ): Promise<boolean> {
    console.log('Request');
    const client = context.switchToWs().getClient();
    const ip = client.conn.remoteAddress;
    const key = this.generateKey(context, ip);
    const ttls = await this.storageService.getRecord(key);

    if (ttls.length >= limit) {
      throw new ThrottlerException();
    }

    await this.storageService.addRecord(key, ttl);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Websocket:

```
@UseGuards(NewThrottlerGuard)
@SubscribeMessage('sendMessage')
sendMessage(
  @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket,
  @MessageBody() message: string,
) {
  client.rooms.forEach((room) => {
    if (room !== client.id) {
      client.broadcast.to(room).emit('message', message);
    }
  });
}
```

Error in console:

```
/node_modules/@nestjs/common/utils/validate-each.util.js:22
    throw new InvalidDecoratorItemException(decorator, item, context.name);
          ^
Error: Invalid guard passed to @UseGuards() decorator (ChatGateway).
at validateEach
```

The file in: @nestjs/common/utils/validate-each.util.js:22

```
function validateEach(context, arr, predicate, decorator, item) {
    if (!context || !context.name) {
        return true;
    }
    console.log(context, arr)
    const errors = arr.some(str => !predicate(str));
    if (errors) {
        throw new InvalidDecoratorItemException(decorator, item, context.name);
    }
    return true;
}
```

i put some console.log then in the terminal it show:

```
[Function: ChatGateway] [ undefined ]
```

In Github Throttler [documentation](https://github.com/nestjs/throttler#working-with-websockets) they say: You cannot bind the guard with APP_GUARD or app.useGlobalGuards() due to how Nest binds global guards.
So, im using @UseGuards()

Comment: I assume you import the guard like `imoprt { NewThrottlerGuard } from './path'`, right? Do you have a github link to this? It looks generally fine in the restricted context I have

Comment: @JayMcDoniel I have: https://github.com/HenriqueRamos13/Private-Chat-Back

Comment: Is this how it is set up in your actual application too? This has a circular reference between the chat gateway and the app module. `chat.gateway` imports `app.,module` imports `chat.module` imports `chat.gateway` ad infinum. This makes the guard show up as `undefined` which Nest throws an error about

Comment: Worked! So the problem was I create the Throttler in the app file. I moved it to another file and worked, u can check on my github. Thank you! @JayMcDoniel

Answer (score 0):

The guard itself was written correctly, but it was put in a location that importing it made a circular reference between files, so when `@UseGuards()` was used it became `@UseGuards(undefined)` which caused the cryptic error message. Moving the guard to a dedicated file will fix the error

Answer (score 0):

I follow your github reference settings and it doesn't work，The following is my code, where is my setting wrong, and the request to ws is not intercepted(In the handleRequest method)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).